# function doesn't work well without setting timeout

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, timeout, settimeout

I have a function whose purpose is to update a list, but it does not work without timeout of a few seconds. Without set timeout the list is updated only when I initializing the application (restart), and with this timeout the list is updating immediately (as needed).
I would like to know how I it can be updated without this timeout (Which causes the program to wait extra time).

JS CODE:

```
 $rootScope.$on("uniqueOpenPackage", function (event, package){
        importOnlyOnce(package).then(
            function (success) { 
            $rootScope.$broadcast('packageListUpdated', {}); 
        },
        function (err) {
            console.log("failed promise");
        }
        )});

        function importOnlyOnce(package) {

            for (i = 0; i < vm.packageList.data.length; i++) {
                //// Package haven't ID in package.json file ////
                if (package.package.package.product.id === undefined) {
                    vm.openPackage(package.package.package);
                    return;
                }
                //// if importing exists package ////
                else if (package.package.package.product.id === vm.packageList.data[i].product.id) {
                         var temp = vm.packageList.data[i];
                         //// if importing opened and exist package ////
                     if  (LoadedPackages.getIndexOfPackageLoaded(temp) != -1){
                         Package.removePackage(package.package.package);
                         var packageIndex = LoadedPackages.getIndexOfPackageLoaded(temp) + 1;
                         LoadedPackages.loadPackage(vm.packageList.data[i]);
                         return;
                     }
                     else{
                         //// if importing unopened and exist package ////
                        Package.removePackage(package.package.package);
                        LoadedPackages.loadPackage(vm.packageList.data[i]);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            vm.openPackage(package.package.package);
        }

$rootScope.$on('packageListUpdated', function (event, data) {
            listPackages();
            _setSelectedPackage(undefined);
        });
```

Comment: I'm guessing the DOM hasn't loaded the necessary elements when running the function. Can you place your JS at the bottom of your page? If you're using jQuery, try putting the function is a $(document).ready function

Comment: mybe try with promises ... with $q ..so after you can do something like ..$rootScope.$on("uniqueOpenPackage", function (event, package) {
            importOnlyOnce(package).then(function () {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('packageListUpdated', {});
            });
        });

Comment: @Tom Cohen can you please check that it works without second parameter (`timeout`), if it works then it's probably DOM issue, DOM is not loaded yet.

Comment: when you put a function in a timeout it goes to JavaScript puts it in queue, till then your DOM loads thus it works with timeout. Even without second parameter in `timeout` it will work.

Comment: i changed $rootScope.$on(...){ } to be asyn. 
how do I change importOnlyOnce function to be asyn also ?

Comment: @shyammakwana.me which parameter do you mean ?